# When any set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be decomposed into disjoint sets, are all these sets always open sets/intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, equivalence-relations

[Proposition 5.3 ("Real Analysis and Foundations", 2nd ed., by Steven Krantz)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2cZ8.jpg)

Supposed that we have a set $U$=($-A$,$A$), where $A$ is a positive real number. If we partition this set into union of disjoint open sets, then it will create a natural singleton as the boundary point of adjacent open sets.

Take for example, we define an equiv. relation where a~b iff sign(a)=sign(b). Then we can partition $U$=($-A$,$0$) $\cup$ {$0$} $\cup$ ($0$,$A$). But then {$0$} is the closed singleton set mentioned above.

So how true again is this proposition or there is a warning underlying it that this is not supposed to be done?

Edit: Some parts that are originally confused were deleted.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130469/discussion-on-question-by-blek-when-any-set-in-mathbbr-can-be-decomposed-in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your title, No. Just because a set can be decomposed into countable pairwise disjoint sets does not mean it can be decomposed into countable pairwise disjoint open/closed intervals.

The clearest example of this is a Vitali set. I will not define the set here, however, it is an uncountably infinite set $V$ such that for any two elements $x,y \in V$,

$$x-y \not\in \mathbb{Q}$$

If this set had a decomposition into countable pairwise open/closed intervals, one of the intervals must be uncountably infinite. But any uncountably infinite interval will contain 2 rational numbers. Their difference will be a rational number, and so this interval is not part of our decomposition (contradiction).

Comment: Thanks! That's so beautiful! I was asking something trivial but it invites such a nice insight. 